# change proxy in firefox programmatically VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, firefox, proxy

I got piece of code which can set proxy ( ip:port ) in webbrowser , is there any way to set proxy in Firefox or Chrome programmatically by VB.net?

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Sub RefreshIESettings(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    ' Filling in structure
    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    ' Allocating memory
    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    ' Converting structure to IntPtr
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox: You could add the settings to the file "prefs.js" found in:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\???.default

Just add the following lines at the end of the file:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.ftp", "localhost");
user_pref("network.proxy.ftp_port", 10);
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 10);
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "localhost");
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 10);
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl", "localhost");
user_pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", 10);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", localhost);
```

Comment: yeah that's it, thank you. but how can I find prefs.js in vb.net, seems the path is dynamic

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") & "Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" for the first part of the path, the right folder is the folder without a "-" at the end!